# How to resolve "Undefined Symbol" error from Linker while moving to 64-bit?

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I have an app with Xcode 6. It worked successfully until I changed the architecture to 64-bit. The linker then gives this error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture 64bit:
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
>     objc-class-ref in Appdelegate.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
>    objc-class-ref in Appdelegate.o

and many other similar.
I already checked the framework linkers, and they are are ok.
How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: you have to make sure that the library that you use is configured for 64bit.

Comment: so maybe the library is old and i need to upgrade it?

Comment: that's the first thing I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Admob was upgraded back in 11/13 to support 64bit, so you should be able to just upgrade your copy:
http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/11/new-google-mobile-ads-sdk-for-ios.html

Comment: i download the last version, but it's completely different!

Comment: Ah, the joys of progress! Sorry, but you're not going  to have much choice as Apple will insist on the 64bit. The only silver lining is that the new library may fix other compatibility problems.

Comment: How did you even end up with 2 years old library? Don't you use CocoaPods? If no, you should.